# How get ASCII characters similar to output of the linux command 'tree'?

Tags: bash, tree

Is there a way to print the ASCII charachter '├── ' and '└──' using a bash or perl script?
I want it be exactly like the output of 'tree'.

```
[root@localhost www]# tree -L 1
.
├── cgi-bin
├── error
├── html
└── icons
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo -e "\0342\0224\0224\0342\0224\0200\0342\0224\0200 \033[01"
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me i got the char '└──'. but how do i print  '├── ' ?

Comment: echo -e "\0342\0224\0234\0342\0224\0200\0342\0224\0200"

Answer (score 6):

## Using Unicode specific character in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

There are 3-4 different answers here, some tips and samples...

### 1. Using special character directly into UTF8 [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script.

```bash
HorizT='├'
HLine='─'
echo $HorizT$HLine$HLine
├──
```

### 2. Finding character value from *output sample*

As you are speaking `tree` as output sample, U could run something like

```bash
tree / | sed -ne '2{p;q}'
├── bin

tree / | sed -ne '2{p;q}' | od -An -t o1
342 224 234 342 224 200 342 224 200 040 142 151 156 012
```

To output your reference as *octal* values.

Knowing that *Unicode* use variable number of bytes, that your reference string hold 3 unicode characters, there look like 3 group of 3 values, begining by `342`.

So you could try:

```bash
printf "\342\224\234\n"
├

printf -v HorizontalT "\342\224\234"
printf -v Hline "\342\224\200"

echo $HorizontalT$Hline$Hline$Hline
├───
```

#### 2.b Same in *pure bash*:

If you try to cut'n paste this in a terminal:

```bash
declare -A shown='()'                  # Array list of already shown characters.
while IFS= read -r line; do                      # For each line in tree output,
    for ((i=0; i<${#line}; i++)); do          # For each character in each line,
        [[ ${line:i:1} == \  ]] && break       # Stop reading line at 1st space!
        if ! [[ -v shown["${line:i:1}"] ]]; then         # If not already shown,
            LANG=C printf -v char %q "${line:i:1}" # Store C printable in $char,
            [[ ${char#\\} == "${line:i:1}" ]] ||    # If printable != character,
                printf 'Char: \47%s\47 => %s\n' "${line:i:1}" "$char"   # print,
            shown["${line:i:1}"]=yes        # Add character to shown array list.
        fi
    done                                                           # Line done,
done < <(tree )    # Done! All this are taking input from tree command's output.
```

You must see:

```
Char: '├' => $'\342\224\234'
Char: '─' => $'\342\224\200'
Char: '│' => $'\342\224\202'
Char: ' ' => $'\302\240'
Char: '└' => $'\342\224\224'
```

**Notes:**

- When running this, your current directory must have at least 1 sub directory, which are not empty, for showing complete output.
- Execution time will depend on tree size! ( You may have to wait for the last `'└'` ;-).

### 3. Searching for specific character by using `charmap`

You could use dedicated Unicode browser, like `charmap` under *Debian Gnome GNU/Linux*:

[image: GNOME Character Map]

Browse and find your character, then on second tab: `Character Details`:

[image: charmap detail]

You may read *Various Useful Representations* `->` *octal escaped*:

```bash
printf '\342\224\234\n'
├
```

### 3+. Printing Unicode fonts using `printf`

Once you know *unicode value*, you could use `printf` for creating variable:

```bash
printf -v char '\U251C'
echo $char
├
```

From there, after some brainstorm:

```bash
string=
for i in 0 2 16 24 {12..60..8} ;do
    printf -v r '\\U25%02X' $i
    printf -v char "$r"
    string+="$char "
done
echo "$string"
─ │ ┐ ┘ ┌ └ ├ ┤ ┬ ┴ ┼
```

Or

```bash
string=
for i in {80..108} ;do
    printf -v r '\\U25%02X' $i
    printf -v char "$r"
    string+="$char "
done
echo "$string"
═ ║ ╒ ╓ ╔ ╕ ╖ ╗ ╘ ╙ ╚ ╛ ╜ ╝ ╞ ╟ ╠ ╡ ╢ ╣ ╤ ╥ ╦ ╧ ╨ ╩ ╪ ╫ ╬
```

### 4. Final `bash` function

Strictly answering SO request:

> I want it be exactly like the output of 'tree'.

Here is a function:

```bash
tree-L1() { 
    local _i indent=0 entry root=${1:-.};
    local -i dirs files;
    [[ $1 == -i ]] && indent=$2 && shift 2;
    echo "$root";
    . <(cd "$root";set -- *;echo ${@@A});
    printf -v indent '%*s' "$indent" '';
    for ((_i=1; _i<=$#; _i++))
    do
        entry=${!_i};
        [[ -d $root/$entry ]] && dirs+=1 || files+=1;
        [[ -L $root/$entry ]] && printf -v entry '%s -> %s' "${!_i}" "$(
            readlink "$root/${!_i}")";
        if ((_i==$#)); then
            printf '%b%b%b%b %s\n' "${indent// /\\U2502   }" \
                \\U2514 \\U2500{,} "$entry";
        else
            printf '%b%b%b%b %s\n' "${indent// /\\U2502   }" \
                \\U251C \\U2500{,} "$entry";
        fi;
    done;
    printf '\n%d directories, %d files\n' $dirs $files
}
```

Then you could try to compare:

```bash
diff <(tree-L1 /etc) <(tree -L 1 /etc)
```

may output **nothing**, as there's **no differences** between *regular `tree -L 1`* output and my function's ouptput!! Or

```bash
diff --width 80 -y <(tree-L1 /etc) <(tree -L 1 /etc)
```

### 5. Browse Unicode table by *character name*

Please have a look at [Is there a (linux) terminal character picker? on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/1784202/178656), I've  posted a little Python unicode library:

```bash
./dumpUnicode | grep 'BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT.*\(HORI\|VERT\)'
```

```
\U002500: '─' BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT HORIZONTAL
\U002502: '│' BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT VERTICAL
\U002504: '┄' BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT TRIPLE DASH HORIZONTAL
\U002506: '┆' BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT TRIPLE DASH VERTICAL
\U002508: '┈' BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT QUADRUPLE DASH HORIZONTAL
\U00250A: '┊' BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT QUADRUPLE DASH VERTICAL
\U00251C: '├' BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT VERTICAL AND RIGHT
\U002524: '┤' BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT VERTICAL AND LEFT
\U00252C: '┬' BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT DOWN AND HORIZONTAL
\U002534: '┴' BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT UP AND HORIZONTAL
\U00253C: '┼' BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT VERTICAL AND HORIZONTAL
\U00254C: '╌' BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT DOUBLE DASH HORIZONTAL
\U00254E: '╎' BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT DOUBLE DASH VERTICAL
\U01FBAF: '' BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT HORIZONTAL WITH VERTICAL STROKE
```

#### 5+ Extracting specials chars from `tree` outputs, with full descriptions

And with previous script, 1st creating a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) *associative array* `u8Table`:

```bash
declare -A u8Table='()'
while IFS=\  read -r cod char dsc; do
    char="${char#\'}" char="${char%\'}"
    u8Table["$char"]="$cod $dsc"
done < <(dumpUnicode | grep -v '^.U0000[2-7]')
```

Then

```bash
declare -A shown='()'
while IFS= read -r line; do
    for ((i=0; i<${#line}; i++)); do
        [[ ${line:i:1} == \  ]] && break
        if ! [[ -v shown["${line:i:1}"] ]]; then
            LANG=C printf -v char %q "${line:i:1}"
            [[ ${char#\\} == "${line:i:1}" ]] ||
                 printf 'Char: \47%s\47 => %-16s %s\n' \
                     "${line:i:1}" "$char" "${u8Table["${line:i:1}"]}"
            shown["${line:i:1}"]=yes
        fi
    done
done < <(tree)
```

```
Char: '├' => $'\342\224\234'  \U00251C: BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT VERTICAL AND RIGHT
Char: '─' => $'\342\224\200'  \U002500: BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT HORIZONTAL
Char: '│' => $'\342\224\202'  \U002502: BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT VERTICAL
Char: ' ' => $'\302\240'      \U0000A0: NO-BREAK SPACE
Char: '└' => $'\342\224\224'  \U002514: BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT UP AND RIGHT
```

#### 6. Further...

Have a look at [Playing with UTF8 in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76256737/1765658)

Answer (score 5):

They look to be a part of the extended ascii codes. You can see them here http://www.asciitable.com/

Also available at the Unicode table here: http://unicode-table.com/en/sections/box-drawing/

[image]

I believe 192, 195 and 196 are the ones you are after.
In Unicode 2501, 2514 and 2523.

**EDIT**

Found a related stack question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753055/how-can-i-display-extended-ascii-codes-characters-in-perl), which recommends printing in Unicode.

> What you want is to be able to print unicode, and the answer is in [`perldoc perluniintro`](http://p3rl.org/UNI).
>   You can use `\x{nnnn}` where n is the hex identifier, or you can do `\N{...}` with the name:

```
perl -E 'say "\x{2514}"; use charnames; say "\N{BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT UP AND RIGHT}"'
```

Comment: asciitable.com is my favorite website of all time

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you landed here, and you just want to display the ascii table like I did at one time, then simply do this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ascii
```

then:

```
ascii
```

This answer my not be directly applicable to the quiz above, but helps those who landed here and were seeking something different like I did one time.

Otherwise, the basic way to see a tree is:

```
echo -e "\0342\0224\0224\0342\0224\0200\0342\0224\0200 \033[01\ cgi-bin \n|"
```

Thanks.